# How to edit the tomcat-maven plugin in eclipse to look for a war in a different folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a maven project which has an embedded apache tomcat 7 built in it. So when I use maven and build this application I finally execute mvn tomcat7:run and it starts the application from a particular folder say C:MyApp/launcher/WebApp/

I have the same project imported into my eclipse as maven project and converted to Java Facets. Now I want to use the eclipse to program and debug this webapp. From RunAs>run configurations>MavenBuild I created a new property. And I also added a new apache tomcat server v8.0.

Now when I run my application from eclipse, i see there is BUILD success message and finally tomcat server runs telling this message

```
>>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) > compile @ XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 2 resources
    [INFO] Copying 3 resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- jrebel-maven-plugin:1.1.5:generate (generate-rebel-xml) @ XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) < compile @ XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp <<<
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp ---
    [INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/XXXX-client-js-sample-webapp
```

But i see it runnning a wrong application. It instead runs a sample webapp which is part of the project.Now where/how to change these settings so that when i start the app from eclipse it deploys the correct webapp

Comment: If you don't manage to get the tomcat plugin to work, you can try the Cargo plugin instead; though it is more complicated to use, it is more flexible and is actively maintained. https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html